# Creating Generic Class to Process List<T>

Tags: c#, generics

I am not seeing how to instantiate a generic class that accepts List as it's type.  Here I want to instantiate the ListAnalyzer class using my List.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks

```
public static void Main()
    {
        List<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog>();
        
        dogs.Add(new Dog()
        {Name = "spike", Breed = "Poodle"});
        
        dogs.Add(new Dog()
        {Name = "george", Breed = "Spaniel"});
        
        dogs.Add(new Dog()
        {Name = "sammy", Breed = "Weimaraner"});
        
        
        Console.WriteLine("Analyzing List");
        
        // Compile error: 
        // Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Dog>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<Dog>>'
        ListAnalyzer<List<Dog>> dogListAnalyzer = new ListAnalyzer<List<Dog>>(dogs);
    }

public class ListAnalyzer<T> where T : List<T>
{
    List<T> _list;
    PropertyInfo[] _listProperties;
    
    public ListAnalyzer(List<T> list)
    {
        _list = list;
        
        _listProperties = _list.GetType().GetProperties();
        
        foreach (var property in _listProperties)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(property.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have `public class ListAnalyzer<T>` and `ListAnalyzer<Dog> dogListAnalyzer = new ListAnalyzer<Dog>(dogs);`

Answer (score 0):

Generic type where constraint makes sure that if you write

```
public class CarList<T> where T : ICar
```

you can only use T:s that implements or are of the type or interface that is to the right of the `:`.

In your case you write

```
public class ListAnalyzer<T> where T : List<T>
```

And that means that you may only use a T that fulfills the constraint that it implements `List<T>`. So if `T` is a `string` it would need to implement `List<string>` wich it doesnt and i cant think of any `T` that would fulfill this constraint.

I think what you want to do is letting `T` only be the thing contained in the list and probably skip the constraint:

```
public class ListAnalyzer<T>
```

Comment: I guess I am trying to ensure that the ListAnalyzer class only accepts List<T> and if any other T is attempted from the constructor I compiler error would be raised.  Maybe this cannot be done unless I do some type checking in the constructor but I was trying to avoid that.  Thanks for the help!